# ng angular typeahead drupal

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

Has anyone got the [angularjs bootstrap-ui "typeahead"](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) widget to play nice with [drupal autocomplete](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_autocomplete.inc/7)?

seems like a match made in heaven

I will try this in the next week or so - but just checking if anyone has a working example before I set out on the journey.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Its not hard.

To achieve the same thing in angular (being served by drupal), have to:

1. get angular and [bootstrap ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) working.
2. create the  element in my view
3. add a function to the controller $scope to access $http ($http needs to be injected as a dependancy into the controller).

In my FAPI form I had a autocomplete_path defined:

```
 '#autocomplete_path' => 'agc/ac/contact/_',
```

So to access the same call back, in my Angular template:

```
 <pre>Model: {{result | json}}</pre>                           
  <input type="text" ng-model="result"                                           
   typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in cities($viewValue)">
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('contactFindControllers', []).controller('contactFindCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.cities = function(cityName) {
    var path = '/agc/ac/contact/_/' + cityName;
    return $http.get(path)
    .then(function(response){
      // see note below regarding "_.values()"
      return _.values(response.data);
        });
  };

}]);
```

FYI: I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930339/how-to-tie-angular-uis-typeahead-with-a-server-via-http-for-server-side-optimi) as a starting point.

Note: my callback returns a JSON object (because I have non-numeric keys) not the array I needed, so I need to extract the values with `_.values()`.
You many not need to use _.values at all (or if facing the same issue just
grab the values from the object *or* modify your call back to 
return a json array)